# How to select add to selected date 1 day using monthcalendar in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this code: `MessageBox.Show(monthCalendar1.SelectionStart.ToString());`
which show me "2012-03-03 00:00:00'

i'd like to have another messagebox with day "2012-03-04 00:00:00" so add to selected day 1 day automaticaly. How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MessageBox.Show(monthCalendar1.SelectionStart.AddDays(1).ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming SelectionStart is of type DateTime, try this:

```
MessageBox.Show(monthCalendar1.SelectionStart.AddDays(1).ToString());
```

[Documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays.aspx)